# displaying data in html page with use of slidetoogle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flip").click(function() {
      $("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

I want to display each tuple in different panel upon clicking the button in particular panel the details of that particular tuple should be shown in slide down panel and once again clicking on the button details should be hidden.

but according to my code only first tuple is correctly functioning.

```html
$num=mysqli_num_rows($res); for($i=1;$i

<=$num; $i++) { while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
  <div>
    <a id="flip" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="#" id="flip">
      <?php echo $row['pname']; ?> </a>

    <div id="panel">
      <p id="flip">
        <?php echo "{$row['startDate']}"; ?> </p>
      <p id="flip">
        <?php echo $row['endDate']; ?> </p>

      <p id="flip">
        <?php echo $row['reference']; ?> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr/>

  <?php
```

Comment: Please post your code along with your question.

Comment: <script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
</script>

Comment: Please add HTML code also. thank you

Comment: $num=mysqli_num_rows($res);
                  for($i=1;$i<=$num; $i++)
                {while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                 {
                    ?>
                    <div>
                    <a id="flip" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="#" id="flip"> <?php echo $row['pname']; ?> </a>
                       <div id="panel">
               <p id="flip"> <?php echo "{$row['startDate']}"; ?> </p>
                        <p id="flip"> <?php echo $row['endDate']; ?> </p>
                        <p id="flip"> <?php echo $row['reference']; ?> </p>

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code there. Also, please add your html and css code as well because we don't know what #flip and #panel etc are actually doing.

Comment: friends now i added my code

Answer (score 0):

remove all the ids, they are unique

you dont need the for loop around the while loop

```
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
?>
<div class="item">
  <a class="toggle btn btn-info btn-lg" href="#">
    <?php echo $row['pname']; ?>
  </a>

  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      <?php echo "{$row['startDate']}"; ?>
    </p>
    <p>
      <?php echo $row['endDate']; ?>
    </p>
    <p>
      <?php echo $row['reference']; ?>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>

<?php 
} 
?>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle("fast");
    });
  }); 
</script>
```